# VSCode sync GitHub always auth

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

[image]

[image]

I want to use VSCode to log in to GitHub to synchronize the previous settings, but I don't know why it keeps showing "Logging in to github.com...." After a long time, it says "Authorization for this extension to use GitHub has not been completed". what should I do?

illustrate:

VSCode version: 1.71.0 (Universal)

I found a way online and changed /etc/hosts
Added the following

```
140.82.112.4 github.com
185.199.108.153 vscode-auth.github.com
185.199.109.153 vscode-auth.github.com
185.199.110.153 vscode-auth.github.com
185.199.111.153 vscode-auth.github.com
```

Previously, ping github.com would time out, but now the local ping github.com is successful. But VSCode still fails. What should I do?

Comment: I have solved the problem. It's caused by the web proxy I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Git Hub account settings -> Integrations -> Applications -> 'Authorized OAuth Apps'.
make sure that access to your GitHub by Vscode is approved.